Filling a listbox in winforms vb.net with JSON list
I am trying to populate a listbox with the following data.  The listbox is called lbxCamera and I need to fill it with the 3 rows of instructions.
I am supposed to use Newtonsoft.Json in the vb.net Winforms environment.
{
    "lbxCamera":
    [
        {"Instructions":"2nd Instruction"},
        {"Instructions":"2nd Instruction"},
        {"Instructions":"3rd Instruction"}
    ]
}

Thanks,
I tried many things but none worked. I am used to pulling data from the database; this is my first time trying to get data from JSON files.

Can you post what you've tried so far? It would clarify whether you have a fixed model to deserialize this JSON to, whether you know in advance the name of the Control to fill up, and what Form contains it - Did you serialize the data? Is this the actual content of the JSON, or just a section of it? Do you need to validate the JSON's content, or the JSON structure? What .NET version are you targeting? What version of Newtonsoft.Json? <- Add the details to the body of the question

All I came with is the json and I do not know how to create objects to add these to either dropdown or listbox
{"Objects":
{
"DropDown": {
"item": [
{
"Instruction": "1st item"
},
{
"Instruction": "2nd item"
},
{
"Instruction": "3rd item"
}
]
},
"ListBox": {
"item": [
{
"Instruction": "1st item"
},
{
"Instruction": "2nd item"
},
{
"Instruction": "3rd item"
}
]
}
}
}

This is my solution: The JSON file is read in if it is found in the file system and is deserialized using Newtonsoft.Json. You have to install Newtonsoft.Json via the Nuget package manager. I simply called the class TestClass because I didn't know what your object was called.
I think there was a lack of understanding because your JSON file consists of a list of dictionaries(of string, string). That's not so common. Because: Why have multiple dictionaries with 1 item when one dictionary containing multiple items would work?
Option Strict On
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public NotInheritable Class TestClass
    <JsonProperty("lbxCamera")>
    Public Property LbxCamera As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
End Class

Option Strict On

Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\new 1.json") Then
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            Dim jsonData As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\new 1.json")
            Dim things As TestClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TestClass)(jsonData)
            For Each dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) In things.LbxCamera
                For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dict
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(kvp.Key & ": " & kvp.Value)
                Next
                ListBox1.Items.Add("---")
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class



Thank you very much Daniel for taking the time.  This solved it.

Daniel, if Json has more than one list as the one I put as an example.  How can I do that for the other lists?  Thanks Daniel

Then you add one more List(Of Dictionary(of... , ...)) to the TestClass.
